# internal server error 500 , when m making post request for registering user , dont know whats wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, thunderclient

*** my index js ***

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const userRoute = require("./routes/users");
const postRoute = require("./routes/posts");
const categoryRoute = require("./routes/categories");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

dotenv.config();

app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/images")));

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
  .then(console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, req.body.name);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json("File has been uploaded");
});
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoute);
app.use("/api/categories", categoryRoute);

app.listen("5000", () => {
  console.log("Backend is running.");
});
```

*** my auth .js ***

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

//REGISTER
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
    const newUser = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPass,
    });

    const user = await newUser.save();
    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//LOGIN
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
    !user && res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials!");

    const validated = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    !validated && res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials!");

    const { password, ...others } = user._doc;
    res.status(200).json(others);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

*** body of request ***

```
{
  "username" : "radha",
  "email" : "krishna@gmail",
  "password" : "radha"
}
```

*** response that i got ***
Status: 500 Internal Server Error

```
{}
```

*** it was working fine when i made it first time then i used body parser package to resolve header too large problem as per the suggestion that i got here but it didnt worked then i removed body parser and uninstalled the packege but now its not working and m getting internal server 500 error  ***

Comment: did you console.log(err) inside the catch function of register route?

Comment: This may be a database error because you saved once but for testing, you are using the same data again. This may be a data duplication error.

Comment: how do i resolve this error @GulshanAggarwal

Comment: Did you console.log(err) inside the register catch function, what do you see there tell me?

Comment: i deleted old data and created new but now am getting axios error header field too large @GulshanAggarwal